# Diagnosing a SQL Server 2012 performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am noticing high CPU spikes on my SQL Server. I ran this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 st.text
               ,st.dbid
               ,st.objectid
               ,qs.total_worker_time
               ,qs.last_worker_time
               ,qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC
```

and noticed the first row contained this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPR_GEOIPCITY]
@myint1 bigint,
@myint2 bigint
 AS
SELECT top 1 city,latitude,longitude,areacode,region
FROM geoipcity
WHERE endipnum_conv >= @myint1
and startipnum_conv <= @myint2
```

This procedure was created years ago and there are no agent jobs or web site templates that trigger the recreation of this procedure. Why would it be listed here?

Comment: I haven't done much with those tables, but I would have thought that what was being recreated was the query plan, not the procedure.  Is this procedure called a lot?

Comment: Maybe has something do to with option recompile

Comment: Yes its called a lot.

Comment: You ask why your procedure is cached, when it is called a lot? Am I right? It is normal behavior. Query optimizer evaluates your SP, pick best plan and cache it, so it hasn't to do the same work in the future and goes exactly to execution. [SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)

Answer (score 0):

sys.dm_exec_query_stats contains statistics about queries which are in the query cache.  When a query is removed from the cache it will no longer show up in this virtual table.  When items are removed from the cache is complex but when they are added is simple.  EVERY QUERY RUN is added to the cache when it is run.  If a query is being run it will be in the cache at some point.

You are ordering your results by total worker time thus the one listed on the top is the one that is taking the most time.  `SPR_GEOIPCITY` uses a lot of cpu time.

You could look at the query plan, but I'll save you some time make an index on `geoipcity.endipnum_conv` and `geoipcity.startipnum` -- you should see your spikes go away.

Comment: I have indexes on them. Must be something else causing the high cpu spike

Comment: @JeffShain interesting.   So the database tells you this routine is causing the problem but you don't believe it.  *shrug*